# QtCreator how to identify which override is being used?

Tags: c++, qt, signals, overloading

In QtCreator when you hover over a Qt function it will give you context help that numbers all the various overloads available for a call.

The question is, in the case of QObject::connect, there are 8 available overloads, how do I know which one is actually being used?

I have existing code and I am trying to identify which overload method is being used so I can clean up the code and use a type to replace:

```
QObject::connect(this
                        ,&clsQtPushBtn::clicked
                        ,[pobjScriptEng, strCall, strFile, strScript]() {
                            if ( strCall.isEmpty() != true ) {
                                QString strScriptWithCall = static_cast<QString>(strScript)
                                                         + static_cast<QString>(strCall) + "();";
                                pobjScriptEng->evaluate(strScriptWithCall);
                            }
                        });
```

What I want to do is replace the parameter, assigning the code below to a temporary variable and assigning that as the parameter instead:

```
   [pobjScriptEng, strCall, strFile, strScript]() {
     if ( strCall.isEmpty() != true ) {
       QString strScriptWithCall = static_cast<QString>(strScript)
                                + static_cast<QString>(strCall) + "();";
       pobjScriptEng->evaluate(strScriptWithCall);
     }
   }
```

This is because I want to reuse the same parameter in other connects without having to duplicate the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have lambdas in the connect so the option 7 of all the possibles overloaded methods

you can use ctrl + space inside the paramters to check which pass better

[image]

Comment: Thank you, is there any way to tell this from the IDE without knowledge of which is correct?

Comment: I'm using an iMAC I think the key sequence may be different?

Comment: Where or how is Func1 defined?  I can't create a local variable using it???